# Why CefSharp indicates 'Not allowed to load local resource: file:///C:/...'?

Tags: c#, cefsharp

I've setup my project and code according to the guides for loading files from the local file system ([Referenced site](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/173/how-to-use-cefsharp-chromium-embedded-framework-csharp-in-a-winforms-application)). The web files are all right there in the project. Even though the two properties are set to enable `FileAccessFromFileUrls` and `UniversalAccessFromFileUrls`, the content in the browser control is still empty and the debugger indicates 'Not allowed to load local resource'. Cannot see the reason why CefSharp won't load the file.

Using version 63.0.3.0

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        InitializeChromium();
        Controls.Add(_chromiumWebBrowser);
    }

    private void InitializeChromium()
    {
        var settings = new CefSettings();
        Cef.Initialize(settings);

        var address = $@"{Application.StartupPath}\HtmlResources\html\index.html";
        _chromiumWebBrowser = new ChromiumWebBrowser(address);

        _chromiumWebBrowser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        _chromiumWebBrowser.IsBrowserInitializedChanged += OnBrowserInitialized;
        _chromiumWebBrowser.FrameLoadEnd += OnFrameLoadEnd;

        _jsToSharp = new JsToSharp(_chromiumWebBrowser);
        _chromiumWebBrowser.JavascriptObjectRepository.Register("jsToSharp", _jsToSharp, true);

        var browserSettings = new BrowserSettings
        {
            FileAccessFromFileUrls = CefState.Enabled,
            UniversalAccessFromFileUrls = CefState.Enabled
        };

        _chromiumWebBrowser.BrowserSettings = browserSettings;
    }
```

Comment: is the `address` value what you expect?

Comment: I'm not familiar with CEF, but aren't you enabling local file access *after* you try to load the page?

Comment: Address should be a valid URi.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check all your html, js, etc files getting copied to the build output directory in the project settings of Visual Studio. In the "Build Action" properties set 'Copy to Output' = 'Copy if newer'.

Comment: That was the problem. I had missed setting that property on a file and it wasn't available in the build product. The error message had me thinking there was a different problem. Thanks!